# Call external arguments within a function in R

Tags: r

I want to run an ANOVA test on several data (Day, Week and Month). My idea was to create a loop that call each dataset (Day, Week and Month). However the following code does not work, because does not recognise the value[i].

```
df1<-data.frame(Day=c(1,2,5,6,9,8),Week=c(22,45,33,3,2,11),Month=c(45,6,7,12,4,7),
           type=c("A","C","B","A","C","B"))

value<-c("Day","Week","Month")

    for(i in 1:length(value)){
    av<-aov(value[i] ~ type, data = data)
    return(av)
    }
```

Do you have any suggestion on how I could improve the code?

Comment: Try `get(value[i])`. Or, maybe better, `df1[[ value[i] ]]`.

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop:

```
m <- aov(cbind(Day, Week, Month) ~ type, data = df1)
summary(m)
```